# How to Sharing or access a relations of intermediate model

Tags: laravel

I have a User Model

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function banks()      //this the relation to banks
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Bank ::class, 'customers', 'user_id', 'bank_id')
            ->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

and Bank model is

```
class Bank extends Model
{
    public function customers()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'customers', 'bank_id', 'user_id')
            ->withPivot('name', 'phone', 'state');
    }
}
```

the intermediate model is Customer

```
class Customer extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'customers';
    protected $fillable = [
            //'id'       this  is the primary key
        'bank_id',
        'user_id',
        'name',
        'phone',
        'state',
    ];

    public function acounts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Account::class, 'customers_id');
    }
}
```

the Account model is

```
class Account extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'accounts';
    protected $fillable = [
        'customer_id',      // this is a foriegin key to customers table 
        'currency_id',
        'balance',
        'state',

    ];
    
    public function accountCurrency()   //  Accounts
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Currency::class, 'currency_id');
    }
}
```

the question is how can access to  "acounts"  relation from user "banks" what is the statment to link account relation  with  banks relation

```
$user = Auth::user();
```

in view

```
@foreach ($user->banks as $bnk)
    <p class="lead">{{ $bnk->bank_name }} </p>

    @foreach ($bnk->accounts as $ account)
        <p class="lead">{{ $account->balance }} </p>
        <p class="lead">{{ $account->accountCurrency->symbol }} </p> 
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

I hope you help me
thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use `hasManyThrough`, check the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Comment: but I have a many to many relation

Comment: I want to add a statement to this relation

Comment: ''' class User extends Authenticatable
{

public function banks()      //this the relation to banks
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Bank ::class, 'customers', 'user_id', 'bank_id')
            
        ->withTimestamps();
    }
}'''

Comment: i would just add this method to your bank model: public function accounts()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Customer::class, Accounts::class);
}